# Is there something like onPressAndHold in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, onpress

I made a custom number counter in react native: when you press  + it increases the  state when you press - it reduces the state value; the issue is that for someone to reach 60 from 0 it take a very long time using onPress, is there something that i could use to have a very long press.

onLongPress did not work, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this

```
<TouchableOpacity onPressIn={this.addOne} onPressOut={this.stopTimer}>
     <Icon name="plus-circle" size={30} color={'white'} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      number: 0,
    };
    this.timer = null;
    this.addOne = this.addOne.bind(this);
    this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this);
  }

  addOne() {
    this.setState({number: this.state.number+1});
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.addOne, 200);
  }

  stopTimer() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }
```